# checking group of dynamically created checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

**I am creating group of check boxes dynamically and one extra check box also for selecting all group at once that one too is generated dynamically**

**this is html output**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="all">all
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="question">a
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="question">b
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="question">c
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="question">d
```

**this is jquery**

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#all").on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("input[type=checkbox][name=question]").prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $("input[type=checkbox][name=question]").prop('checked', false);
        }
    });     

});
```

this is implementation.

It works fine when checkboxes are not generated dynamically

**But when they are generated dynamically code has bug**

I am able to check whole group but
I am not able to check single checkbox

**This is dynamically generated code**

```
$('#demo3').on('change', function() {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked')) {
        var value = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val();
        alert(value);
        $("#demo3").hide();

        $.getJSON("json/question.json", function(jd) {

            var size = jd.length;


            var table = "<table><tr><th><input id=\"" + "selectall" + "\" type=\"" + "checkbox" + "\"/>" +
                    "</th><th>Question</th><th>Option A</th>" + "<th>Option B</th><th>Option C</th>" +
                            "<th>Option D</th><th>Answer</th></tr>";


            for (var n = 0; n < size; n++) {


                table += "<tr><td>" + "<input name=\"" + "question" + "\" type=\"" + "checkbox" + "\" value=\"" + jd[n].questionid + "\"/>" + 
                "</td><td>" + jd[n].question + "</td>" + "<td>" + jd[n].a + "</td><td>" + jd[n].b + "</td>" + "<td>" + jd[n].c + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + jd[n].d + "</td>" + "<td>" + jd[n].ans + "</td></tr>";


            }
            table += "</table>";
            $('#demo4').html(table);

        });

    }
});

$('#demo4').on('change', function() {
    if ($("input[type=checkbox][id=selectall]").is(":checked")) {
        $("input[type=checkbox][name=question]").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("input[type=checkbox][name=question]").prop('checked',false);
    }

});
```

Comment: **1.** `$("document")` ==> `$(document)` **2.** `$("#all").on('change',` ==> `$(document).on('change', "#all"`  **Answer:** `$(document).on('change', '#all', function() {
  $(':checkbox[name="question"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});`

Comment: Read Event delegation. Try this: `$('body').on('change', '#all', function() {}`. Also correct `$("document").ready(function() {` to `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Comment: didnt get it correctly

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand demo4 and demo3 are container elements like div in which you are adding a table which has dynamic HTML.

You could try

```
  $('#demo4').on('change','#<checkboxid>',function() {
```

checkboxid will be the id that you want to track.

Hope that helps!